# How to make a forloop without using for statement

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an editor for a map, I need to make the map editor run faster, and I was told remove each nested for loop and do them without a for statement, could somebody guide me towards how I could do such a thing?

```
var tiles = [];
var draw = 0;
var w = 0;
var h = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tile-selector img').click(function () {
        draw = $(this).attr("tile");
    });
});

function run() {
    w = $("#w").val();
    h = $("#h").val();

    for (var x = 0; x < h; x++) {
        tiles[x] = [];
        for (y = 0; y < w; y++) {
            tiles[y] = [];
            $("#box").append("<img src='src/" + draw + ".gif' x='" + x + "' y='" + y + "' height='15' width='15'></img>");
            tiles[x][y] = draw;
        }
        $("#box").append("<br />");
    }


    $("#box img").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "src/" + draw + ".gif");
        tiles[$(this).attr("x")][$(this).attr("y")] = draw;
    });
}

function end() {
    var output = "";
    for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            if (tiles[x][y] > 0) {
                output += "tiles[" + x + "+" + y + "*width] =" + tiles[x][y] + ";\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
    $("#output").val(output);
}
```

Removed first loop and put tiles[y] = []; in the nested loop

Comment: put `tiles[y] = [];` from first loop in second loop before nested loop ;) and remove your first loop.

Comment: change your x and y loop around in the `run` method, Most languages use row major order http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Comment: @Givi, so removed my first loop, and put tile[i] = []; before the first nested?

Comment: Yes, and look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/BLbhE/)

Comment: apart from avoiding too many calls to `append()`, you should use event delegation too.

Answer (score 0):

For this loop

```
    for(var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            $("#box").append("<img src='src/" + draw +".gif' x='"+ x +"' y='"+ y +"' height='15' width='15'></img>");              
            tiles[x][y] = draw;
        }
        $("#box").append("<br />");
    }
```

a couple of things, Changing the order of the loop may help due to javascript using row major order.

taking the `$('#box')` outside will help or even removing it all together so for example

```
    var box = "";
    for(var x = 0; z < w; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            box += "<img src='src/" + draw +".gif' x='"+ x +"' y='"+ y +"' height='15' width='15'></img>";              
            tiles[x][y] = draw;
        }
        box += "<br />";
    }
    $('#box').append(box);
    box = null;
```

should speed it up

Comment: Thats just stopped it from running

Comment: Whats in the console ?